# Add/Remove an id if exists/not exists in swatch gallery

Tags: javascript

I am making and handleClick function for a gradient swatch gallery, and the click is to add an id of "bg-gradient" to the clicked element, then if another swatch is clicked, remove that id and add it to the newly clicked swatch, so that there is only one element at any time with the id of"bg-gradient"  Currently code is nearly working, but adding the id to every clicked swatch, which is no good. This should be fairly simple but cant get it to work. Code is below, and screenshot shows it is adding the id to all the swatches (4).

```
handleSwatch(){
    let el = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');
    for(let i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (!document.querySelector("swatch#bg-gradient")) {
      el[i].setAttribute('id', 'gradient');
    } else {
        alert('Element exists!');
    }
      });
    }
   }
 }

[![Remove first (or set if not exist), add new id to clicked element][1]][1]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.swatch').forEach(_ => {
  _.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.swatch#bg-gradient').forEach(swatch => swatch.removeAttribute('id'));
    _.setAttribute('id', 'bg-gradient');
  })
})
```

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ongh04dt/2/).

Comment: Indeed, that worked exactly as required, am now just looking for way to swap that clicked swatch in to the main div id "bodybg" at top of page for further editing, ie change the hex values in there and save it again back to the same location, as in this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034686/swap-bg-gradient-images-in-a-gallery-of-swatches  Thanks